# jQuery conflicting - .load and hover intent

Tags: jquery, load, conflict, hoverintent

I am trying to run these two seperate scripts on one site. This is how they look:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

        var name = "";

        $(".home-roll-box").hover(function() {
            name = $(this).attr("id");
            $("#image-"+name).stop().show().animate({ opacity: 1 });
        }, function() {
            name = $(this).attr("id");
            $("#image-"+name).stop().animate({ opacity: 0 });
        });
        });
</script>
<!--/Band Images-->

<!--Navigation-->
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajaxSetup ({ cache: false });

        $('ul.navigation li a').click(function() {
        $('ul.navigation li.page_item.current_page_item').removeClass('current_page_item');
        $('ul.navigation li.page_item a.active').removeClass('active');
        $('#content-wrap').animate({ 
            top: "-2000px"
        }, 1000 );

            var targetPage = $(this).attr('href');
            targetPage += " #content";

        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#content-wrap').load(targetPage, function() {
                $('#content-wrap').animate({ 
                    top: "0px"
                }, 1000 );
            });
        });
        $(this).addClass('active'); 
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

They both work individually, but not together. It seems to be the `return false;` at the bottom of the second script that is causing the issues.

Comment: `return false;` prevents the click event from "bleeding" to the other elements in the page and also prevents the normal click behavior to occur (like following a link, or submitting a form). Do you really need that `return false;` there?

Comment: @Richard Neil Ilagan - Thanks. Yes, if that is not there, the page loads as normal (without the ajax effect.).

Comment: Ah, then you just want to stop the click from actually following into the link. Check out @rcravens' answer below; that should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an evt parameter in your click handler and then calling

```
evt.preventDefault();
```

Here is a good description of the differences: http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: Sorry, @rcravens - you will have to be more specific in the placement of the code!

Comment: just read the link you posted. I have added in the `evt.preventDefault();` and although the `.load` functions work, it still seems to be interfering with the other script...